# ionic white screen of death - improper URL access

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

We have an ionic app which should load a url/template from local based on angular state it is being sent to, however, it tries loading just the end part of the url, which it does not find as expected, and ends into white screen of death.

For example:

For the url:

[image]

instead of loading the complete URL, it just starts looking for file:///#members, which it does not find and the launch breaks.

Weird part is, everything works fine when in browser, and also when connecting to the local server, but when we connect to the remote server, ionic is somehow not able to resolve/identify the URLs.

Any inputs on why this would be happening would be really helpful? We are stuck on this for couple of weeks now. :(

Comment: When a white screen of death appears in Ionic App, it is an indicator that the library somewhere failed to load, look in the Console of the browser, when connected to the mobile device, it should give you a clue. Actually, show us what the console says. Even a syntax error can break the whole thing.

Comment: the console actually shows only " file:///#members" and breaks.... I guess I am near finding the issue for this. will update in a while

Comment: Sounds like a router problem, check in there. Since there is no code, and we cannot help you further, we are not a remote debugging site while fishing for answers in this comments. You say *"We are stuck on this for couple of weeks"*, then why not ask whoever is in the group?

Comment: @t0mm13b I did not claimed you to be a remote debugging site, forcing anyone to answer. It was a question to anyone who has experienced this before, like I did and posted my answer as below. Since you might be aware, once one figures out which part of code is breaking, it's easier to solve the problem, so I had no code to share here except the console message written in the original question itself, else we would have solved the problem. Thanks for your time anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly overlook in the code. It works fine in the browser, but breaks in the ionic/cordova. The issue was a improper change in location with command :: `$window.location.href("/#members")` 
instead of 
`$state.go`.

This was leading to file:///#members which was failing since this does not exist, aleading to white screen. This needs to be replaced by proper "$state.go('whatever_state_member_url_represents')"